# How inherit to unnamed class and Override its method in OpenERP V8 (Odoo)

Tags: inheritance, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8

I want to inherit to the class called **AuthSignupHome** for override its method called **do_signup**, but this class haven't a *_name* attribute.

The route of the **AuthSignupHome**  class is: *odoo/addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py*

I readed to override a method, it's necessary re-define the class' attributes, but it haven...and I don't need it, I'm a little confused for that!

I'm new in odoo, please clarify on easy way, how can I do it?

**EDIT:** It's a web controller, I was reading the inherit and override from, can anyone provide me a guideline to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, first building a web module, and the main.py controller

`class MyClass(openerp.addons.auth_signup.controllers.main.AuthSignup):`

inside I override the method

`def do_signup(self, qcontext):`

, thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the old the old OpenERP document: http://odoo-documents.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/http.html

```
class MyController(openerp.http.Controller):
    @route('/some_url', auth='public')
    def handler(self):
        return stuff()
```

To override a controller, inherit from its class and override relevant methods, re-exposing them if necessary:

```
class Extension(MyController):
    @route()
    def handler(self):
        do_before()
        return super(Extension, self).handler()
```

> decorating with route() is necessary to keep the method (and route)
>   visible: if the method is redefined without decorating, it will be
>   “unpublished”
>
> the decorators of all methods are combined, if the overriding method’s
>   decorator has no argument all previous ones will be kept, any provided
>   argument will override previously defined ones